# Unable to find Typeof if C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

While trying to set a property of a datagrid cell in WPF C# I found a post on stack that provides what looks like exactly the code I need (hopefully) - oddly enough I can't get it to compile as I cannot seem to find how to properly declare Typeof.

Code:

```
        var datagrid = new DataGrid();
        Style columnStyle = new Style(Typeof(TextBlock));

        datagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            ElementStyle = columnStyle
        }
```

Original code posting:
[Set DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle by background code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089541/set-datagridtextcolumn-elementstyle-by-background-code)

What I am trying to do is mimic the following to enable textwrapping:

```
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                        </Style>
```

The issue is the Typeof when declaring my Style, the compiler outs the following errors:

> The name 'Typeof' does not exist in the current context
>   'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

I did a bit of searching to see in what Typeof is defined in C# but actually couldn't find anything ... anyone have any clues?

Comment: Try typeof lowercase.

Comment: if you searched for "C# Typeof" you never saw that typeof was written lowercase? :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# is case sensitive

```
Typeof != typeof
```